# Overlap / intersection between subsets of rows in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in Sql Server, one containing IDs for files and the slides contained in those original files, and another for "sections" that can contain slides from one or more of the files, potentially in arbitrary order, duplicated, and/or with some slides eliminated.

Sample data looks like this:

`FileSlide`

```
FileID       SlideID
214          716
214          717
214          718
223          770
223          771
223          772
223          773
223          774
223          775
```

`SectionSlide`

```
SectionID    SlideID
527          716
527          718
527          717
527          770
527          773
527          774
527          775
527          774
```

I originally didn't need a "SectionFile" relation, but now I do need that information to see which files were chosen for a particular section, regardless of slide details.  My problem is examining the slide IDs between the `SectionSlide` and `FileSlide` tables to see whether there's an overlap between the slides in any given File-Section pair.  I would like to find all File-Section pairs that share slides.

For the sample data above, output would look like this:

`SectionFileCandidates`

```
SectionID    FileID
527          214
527          223
```

What is the query to produce this output?

Is it possible to calculate a metric that indicates what proportion of the original file's slides exists in the section?

For the sample data above, output would look like this:

`SectionFileCandidates`

```
SectionID    FileID    Overlap
527          214       1.00
527          223       0.67
```

...that is, 3 out of 3 slides from file 214 are in section 527, and 4 out of 6 slides from file 223 are in section 527.

I was originally trying to compare groups of rows using the `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` clause, but could not figure it out.

How can I do these two queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Both queries are possible!**

---

First query:

```
SELECT s.SectionID,
       f.FileID
FROM SectionSlide s
INNER JOIN FileSlide f ON s.SlideID = f.SlideID
GROUP BY s.SectionID, f.FileID
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SectionID,
                f.FileID
FROM SectionSlide s
INNER JOIN FileSlide f ON s.SlideID = f.SlideID
```

---

Second query:

```
select s.SectionID, f.FileID,
       round(((count(distinct f.SlideID)*1.0) / aux.total), 2) as 'Overlap'
from SectionSlide s
inner join FileSlide f on f.SlideID = s.SlideID
inner join (select f.FileID, count(f.SlideID) as 'total'
            from FileSlide f
            group by f.FileID) aux on aux.FileID = f.FileID
group by f.FileID, s.SectionID, aux.total
```

Comment: But what about overlap column

Comment: @ShehzadBilal is in the second query.

Comment: As a comment, in SQL Server the "/" on integers returns an integer, so the overlap will be either 0 or 1.  Throw in a "*1.0" to convert to a float.

Comment: @aF., I think even with the "*1.0" the overlap will always still be 1.0, because that COUNT/COUNT calculation is being done on the post-inner-join data. That is, for FileID 223 above, the query is doing 4/4 and not 4/6.  Is that correct?

Comment: @aF. Yes, it is as I suspected.  Always 1.0 for the Overlap--the two COUNTs are always the same because they are the post-JOIN counts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sort of confused by your question, but the query below should get you your desired results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fs.FileId, ss.SectionId
FROM FileSlide fs
INNER JOIN SectionSlide ss
ON fs.SlideId= ss.SlideId
```

Comment: Yep, that does the trick, thanks.  The non-overlap calculation version is a lot easier than I thought.